# Find pairs of words in dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, algorithm, tuples

I want to find pairs of words in a file called `dictionary.txt` based on given strings of
**distinct** letters such as `GRIHWSNYP`.

`dictionary.txt` looks like this:

```
AARHUS
AARON
ABABA
ABACK
ABAFT
ABANDON
ABANDONED
ABANDONING
ABANDONMENT
ABANDONS
ABASE
ABASED
...
```

Some examples of expected output:

```
    >>> f('ABCDEFGH')
    There is no solution.
    >>> f('GRIHWSNYP')
    The pairs of words using all (distinct) letters in "GRIHWSNYP" are:
    ('SPRING', 'WHY')
    >>> f('ONESIX')
    The pairs of words using all (distinct) letters in "ONESIX" are:
    ('ION', 'SEX')
    ('ONE', 'SIX')
    >>> f('UTAROFSMN')
    The pairs of words using all (distinct) letters in "UTAROFSMN" are:
    ('AFT', 'MOURNS')
    ('ANT', 'FORUMS')
    ('ANTS', 'FORUM')
    ('ARM', 'FOUNTS')
    ('ARMS', 'FOUNT')
    ('AUNT', 'FORMS')
    ('AUNTS', 'FORM')
    ('AUNTS', 'FROM')
    ('FAN', 'TUMORS')
    ('FANS', 'TUMOR')
    ('FAR', 'MOUNTS')
    ('FARM', 'SNOUT')
    ('FARMS', 'UNTO')
    ('FAST', 'MOURN')
    ('FAT', 'MOURNS')
    ('FATS', 'MOURN')
    ('FAUN', 'STORM')
    ('FAUN', 'STROM')
    ('FAUST', 'MORN')
    ('FAUST', 'NORM')
    ('FOAM', 'TURNS')
    ('FOAMS', 'RUNT')
    ('FOAMS', 'TURN')
    ('FORMAT', 'SUN')
    ('FORUM', 'STAN')
    ('FORUMS', 'NAT')
    ('FORUMS', 'TAN')
    ('FOUNT', 'MARS')
    ('FOUNT', 'RAMS')
    ('FOUNTS', 'RAM')
    ('FUR', 'MATSON')
    ('MASON', 'TURF')
    ('MOANS', 'TURF')
```

I tried:

```
    dictionary = 'dictionary.txt'
    solutions = []
    clean_dictionary = [i for i in dictionary if len(i)== len(set(i))] # Filter out words without repeated letters.

    for word in clean_dictionary:
        if not set(word) - set(letters):
            first_word = word
            second_letters = set(letters) - set(word)
            for second in clean_dictionary:
                if set(second) == set(second_letters):
                    second_word = second
                    pair = tuple(sorted((first_word, second_word)))
                    solutions.append(pair)
                    solutions = sorted(set(solutions))

    if not solutions:
        print('There is no solution.')
    else:
        print(f'The pairs of words using all (distinct) letters '
              f'in "{letters}" are:'
             )
        for solution in solutions:
            print(solution)
```

which seemed to work but quite slowly. I am wondering how I can improve the code to make it more efficient or if there is a better way to do this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Reminds me of [How to unscramble a word and find all its matches in a txt file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71850401/2472827); might check out that for inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can speedup your computation by building a table to lookup words which contain the remaining letters, rather than iterating over all the words and testing them one by one.

I also treat the pairs as unordered pairs- if you want to return both `("abc", "def")` and `("def", "abc")`, just remove the last if statement.

```py
def preprocess(dictionary):
    clean_dictionary = [word for word in dictionary if len(word) == len(set(word))]

    lookup_table = defaultdict(list)
    for word in clean_dictionary:
        ordered_word = "".join(sorted(word))
        lookup_table[ordered_word].append(word)
    return clean_dictionary, lookup_table

def get_pairs(dictionary, letters):
    dictionary, letter_table = preprocess(dictionary)
    letters = set(letters)

    for word1 in dictionary:
        if letters.issuperset(word1):
            ordered_word = "".join(sorted(letters.difference(word1)))
            for word2 in letter_table[ordered_word]:
                if word1 < word2:
                    yield word1, word2
```

You could speed up queries even further by building out a trie and then walking the trie to find only the words that are subsets of the given letters, skipping over invalid words. This would only be worthwhile if you were going to perform multiple queries on the same dictionary, and if you're still seeing performance issues even with the above solution.